# Why doesn't this SELECT statment have a FROM?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion

```
<CFIF ListLen(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.reasonString, ";") gt 0>
    <CFQUERY name="insertReasons" datasource="#REQUEST.dsn#">
        INSERT INTO TWelcomeHome_Reason
        (ReasonID, SubReasonID, SurveyID)
        SELECT #sanitize(ListFirst(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.reasonString, ";"))#, #sanitize(getLatestSurveyID.SurveyID)# 
        <CFLOOP list="#sanitize(ListRest(SESSION.WHSurveyStruct.reasonString, ';'))#" index="thisReason" delimiters=";">
            UNION ALL
            SELECT #sanitize(thisReason)#, #sanitize(getLatestSurveyID.SurveyID)#
        </CFLOOP>

    </CFQUERY>
```

I'm trying to understand what this does. I'm confused with the loop, why don't the select statements have a `FROM`? Ok they are just scalars.

What about how there's one select statement on the outside of the loop and one on the inside?  I sort of don't get the point on `union all`. And how come there are 3 columns being specified (ReasonID, SubReasonID, SurveyID) but in each `select` 2 values are given?

dumped:

> struct
>
> CACHED: false EXECUTIONTIME: 0 RECORDCOUNT: 8 SQL: INSERT INTO
>   TWelcomeHome_Reason           (ReasonID, SubReasonID, SurveyID)           SELECT 6,
>   18, 245 
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 6, 21, 245
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 6, 24, 245
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 3, 5, 245
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 3, 6, 245
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 3, 8, 245
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 3, 11, 245
>                 UNION ALL
>                 SELECT 3, 7, 245
>
> ---

Comment: `UNION ALL` simulates a resultset. It is a way of merging multiple records together and inserting them all at once. As far as having the difference in the number of columns in the `INSERT` list versus the resultset - that should *not* work. I would check the debug output to verify that it even executes at all. I would be surprised if it did, because the mismatch should cause a syntax error.

Comment: @Leight scarily enough it does work. Must be some kind of hack.

Comment: Hm.. what is the actual sql generated by that code?  Add the `result` attribute to the query and `cfdump` it.

Comment: @Leigh the `union all` joins rows, not columns right? one sec i'm on it

Comment: Yes. So with Bort's example it creates two rows each containing one column: row 1: foo and row 2: bar.  BTW: Which db and version are you using. I am assuming some flavor of MS SQL by the `tsql` tag.

Comment: @Leigh I'm having some trouble adding cfdump and result. `<CFQUERY name="insertReasons" datasource="#REQUEST.dsn#" result="dbReply">`...`   <cfdump var="#insertReasons.sql#">
   <cfdump var="#insertReasons.cache#">
   <cfoutput>
    #dbReply#
   </cfoutput>` says elements undefined. I'll continue to work at this by myself and reply once I've got the output.

Comment: `INSERT`s do not return a resultset. Dump the "result" variable name, not the query ie `<cfdump var="#dbReply#`>.

Comment: Ok please see edit on original post

Comment: Well the generated SQL shows **three** values in the `SELECT`, not two, which is fine. So there is no problem. This thread is getting long and I think Bort answered your original question already. So if you have further questions, maybe it is time to open a new one :)

Comment: It is possible your input variables contain a list of values like "3, 5" or perhaps you are looking at the wrong code. But it is impossible to say without seeing the raw input and udf code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like it is just `SELECT`ing scalar values, not records from any table.  So

```
INSERT INTO myTable
SELECT 'foo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar'
```

will insert two records into myTable, `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that it's not selecting from a table. So there's no table to `FROM` from.

If you execute:

```
INSERT INTO TableSomething (ColumnA)
SELECT 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B'
```

It will insert A and B into ColumnA.

ColdFusion is creating the data to insert rather than pulling from a table.